Why is my AWS Elastic Beanstalk website showing a "dangerous website" warning despite using SSL and a custom domain?
I have deployed my website on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a custom domain and SSL certificate, but when I access the site, it shows a "dangerous website" warning. I have tried using Google Search Console's HTML file verification method, but the issue persists.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Set up SSL using AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) and attached it to my Elastic Load Balancer.
Configured a custom domain via Route 53 and ensured the DNS records are correct.
Verified the SSL certificate is active and working for the domain.
Used Google Search Console to verify ownership with the HTML file method, but the warning still appears.
Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening, and how I can resolve the "dangerous website" warning?
Additional Details:
Platform: AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Python/Flask)
Domain: [Your custom domain]
SSL: AWS ACM
Error Message: "This website is dangerous" (as seen in Chrome)
Browser: Chrome
Any help or suggestions on fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

Just to be clear, you are entering https://your-custom-domain-name into the browser address bar? Not http:// and the website isn't redirecting the browser to a different domain, or redirecting to an http:// URL? Are you seeing the error in other web browsers like Firefox, or only in Chrome?

No, it is not redirecting. but thank you for your support.

Does your domain name happen to be very similar to well-known domains so that it could be considered an instance of typosquatting? Are you using a TLD that is known for less-than-trustworthy content?
